# Writing a LinkedList destructor?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

Is this a valid LinkedList destructor? I'm still sort of confused by them.

I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.

```
 LinkedList::~LinkedList()
 {
   ListNode *ptr;

   for (ptr = head; head; ptr = head)
   {
     head = head->next
     delete ptr;
   }
}
```

So at the beginning of the loop, pointer ptr is set to hold the address of head, the first node in the list. head is then set to the next item, which will become the beginning of the list once this first deletion takes place. ptr is deleted, and so is the first node. With the first iteration of the loop, pointer is set to head again.

The thing that concerns me is reaching the very last node. The condition "head;" should check that it is not null, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try running the code through a debugger to see if it works?

Comment: @Manuel, because debuggers on certain platforms are not integrated, and are hard to use?

Comment: i know I will get shot for this (somebody always does , but i'm a beleiver). head is a member variable, you really should have naming convention for member variables, like m_head or head_

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not do it much much simpler - with an elegant `while`-loop instead of trying to carefully analyze whether that overcompilcated `for`-loop is correct?

```
ListNode* current = head;
while( current != 0 ) {
    ListNode* next = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = next;
}
head = 0;
```

Comment: of course, this will work..but whether the original code mentioned by OP will work?

Comment: I should remark that `current` never changes and `next` is never used. Was it meant as a bad pun toward the OP ?

Comment: @Matthieu M.: No bad puns intended. Would you please elaborate on "never changes" and "never used"?

Answer (score 5):

You can run it through a debugger or you can run it through that bit of wetware inside your skull - both will show you that it works fine. For example, let's start with the list:

```
head(47) -> [47]single_node -> [NULL]end-of-list.
```

Running that list through your statements:

- `ptr = head` sets `ptr` to 47.
- `head` is non-zero so enter loop.
- `head = head->next` sets `head` to NULL.
- `delete ptr` will delete the `single_node`.
- `ptr = head` sets `ptr` to NULL.
- `head` is now NULL (0) so exit loop.

There you go, you've deleted the only entry in the list and `head` is now set to NULL. That's all you need to do.

You can do a similar thing with a longer list or an empty list, you'll find it's still okay (there's no real difference between a one-element list and a fifty-element list).

As an aside, I'm not a big fan of treating pointers as booleans - I'd rather write it as something like:

```
for (ptr = head; head != NULL; ptr = head)
```

It makes the code read better in my opinion and you don't really sacrifice any performance (unless you have a brain-dead compiler). But that's a matter of taste.

Re your comment:

> The thing that concerns me is reaching the very last node. The condition "head;" should check that it is not null, but I'm not sure if it will work.

It will work. A value of zero will be treated as false so you'll find that you never dereference head->next when head is NULL simply because you will have exited the loop body before that point (or not even entered the body if the list is empty).

Any other pointer value will be treated as true and you will enter or continue the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

> > The condition "head;" should check that it is not null, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Yes, "head" by itself is the same as "head != null" -- but why use a meaningless typing shortcut if even you find it confusing? It's only 6 more keystrokes (and generates identical machine code), so go for the long form.

Additionally, your code is a bit more complicated than necessary because you are using a `for()` construct.  Why not use a `while()`?  Your code will be much cleaner.

Finally, I realize you are doing this as a learning exercise, but keep in mind that list<> is in the standard library --- Linked lists are official a "Solved Problem".

Comment: What I meant was, given that head may be null, would I run into problems accessing "next"? From what I understand, head would point to the last node, and accessing next would contain null instead of an address to the next node.

Answer (score 2):

Tested OK

Destructor for class List

```
List::~List()
{
    Node *n = this->front, *current = NULL; //initialization part

    while(n)                               //start cleanup of nodes of the list
    {
        current = n;
        n=n->next;
        delete(current);
    }

    front = end = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be correct, you should try running it with e.g. valgrind and see what it says. However, I would write it like this:

```
for (ListNode *current = head, *next; current; current = next) {
    next = current->next;
    free(current);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is a better approach for freeing/deleting the memory using destructor of a Linked-List.

```
List()::~List()
            {
                for( Link* ptr= Head; Head; Head= Head->next)
                {
                    delete ptr;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are missing a line, which explains the negative score. You need to set ptr = Head before every delete call, not just on the first one, as you have done above.