# Class destructor, runtime error: Unhandled exception - Stack overflow

Tags: c++, runtime-error, stack-overflow, destructor, unhandled-exception

The destructor for List appears to work, but having trouble with the destructor for Element and List_iter:

*Unhandled exception : 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002E2F78).*

List:

```
#ifndef GUARD_List_h
#define GUARD_List_h

#include "Element.h"
#include "List_iter.h"


template <typename T>
class List {

public:
    List() : begins(new Element<T>), ends(new Element<T>), Element_count(0) {

        begins->t_flag = 'b';
        ends->t_flag = 'e';     

        // double link: begins & ends 
        begins->next = ends;
        ends->prev = begins;        
    }
    virtual ~List()  {
        while (begins->next != ends) {
            begins->prev = begins->next;
            begins->next = begins->next->next;
            delete begins->prev;
        }
        delete begins;
        delete ends;
    }

    typedef List_iter<T> iterator;

    iterator begin(void) const {

        iterator it(begins);
        return it;
    }
    iterator end(void) const {

        iterator it(ends);
        return it;
    }

    void push_back(const T val)  {

        Element<T>* elem = new Element<T>;      // create: new-elem         
        elem->data = val;                       // set data

        elem->prev = ends->prev;                // link: new-elem to last-data-elem
        ends->prev->next = elem;                // link: last-data-elem to new-Element                              

        elem->next = ends;                      // link: new-elem to List-end               
        ends->prev = elem;                      // link: List-end to new-elem   

        Element_count++;                        // update: when List grows      
    }
    T at(const size_t pos)  const {

        return get_Element(pos)->data;
    }
    void del(const size_t pos) const  {

        Element<T>* elem = get_Element(pos);    // get: Element for deletion        

        elem->prev->next = elem->next;          // rejoin: double link
        elem->next->prev = elem->prev;          // rejoin: double link

        delete elem;

        Element_count--;                        // update: when List shrinks

    }
    void clear(void) {

        Element<T>* ep = begins->next;
        Element<T>* ep_next = ep->next;

        while (ep->t_flag != 'e'){

            delete ep;
            ep = ep_next;
            ep_next = ep->next;
        }

        begins->next = ends;
        ends->prev = begins;

        //begins->data = 0r;
        //ends->elem_ID = 0;

        Element_count = 0;

    }

    size_t size(void) const {
        return Element_count;
    }
    bool empty(void) const {

        if (Element_count == 0){ return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }


private:
    Element<T>* begins;                           // List begins
    Element<T>* ends;                             // List ends
    size_t Element_count;                         // List size

    Element<T>* get_Element(const size_t pos) const     {

        if (empty())                        {
            std::cerr << "No Element - Empty List";
            throw;
        }
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= Element_count){
            std::cerr << "No Element - Out of Range";
            throw;
        }

        iterator it;

        // Determine the more efficent iteration direction(forward or reverse) ? 
        if ((Element_count / 2) > pos) {

            it = begin();
            for (size_t i = 0; i <= pos; i++){
                it++;
            }

        }
        else {

            it = end();
            for (size_t i = size() - pos; i > 0; i--){
                it--;
            }
        }

        return it.elem;
    }

};
#endif
```

Element:

```
#ifndef GUARD_Element_h
#define GUARD_Element_h

template <class T>
class List;

template <class T>
class List_iter;


template <class T>
class Element {

public:
    Element() : prev(nullptr), next(nullptr), data(), t_flag(' ') {}
    virtual ~Element()  {
        delete prev;
        delete next;        
    }
    friend List<T>;
    friend List_iter<T>;

private:
    Element<T> *prev;
    Element<T> *next;

    T data;
    int elem_ID;
    char t_flag;
};
#endif
```

List_iter:

```
#ifndef GUARD_List_iter_h
#define GUARD_List_iter_h

template <class T>
class List;


template <class T>
class List_iter {

public: 
    List_iter(Element<T>* e = nullptr) : elem(e) {}
    virtual ~List_iter()  {
        delete elem;
    }
    friend List<T>;

    T operator*(void){

        if (elem->t_flag == 'e'){

            elem = elem->prev;
        }
        else if (elem->t_flag == 'b'){

            elem = elem->next;
        }
        return elem->data;
    }

    Element<T>* operator++(void) {

        if (elem->next->t_flag == 'e'){
            return nullptr;
        }

        elem = elem->next;
        return elem;
    }
    Element<T>* operator--(void) {

        if (elem->prev->t_flag == 'b'){
            return nullptr;
        }

        elem = elem->prev;
        return elem;

    }
    List_iter operator+(const int val) {

        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++){

            this->elem = this->elem->next;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    List_iter operator-(const int val) {

        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++){

            this->elem = this->elem->prev;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const List_iter& rhs) const {

        return rhs.elem != elem;
    }
    bool operator>(const List_iter& rhs) const {

        return (this->elem->elem_ID > rhs.elem->elem_ID);
    }
    bool operator<(const List_iter& rhs) const {

        return (this->elem->elem_ID < rhs.elem->elem_ID);
    }
    bool operator>=(const List_iter& rhs) const {

        return (this->elem->elem_ID >= rhs.elem->elem_ID);
    }
    bool operator<=(const List_iter& rhs) const {

        return (this->elem->elem_ID <= rhs.elem->elem_ID);
    }


private:
    Element<T>* elem;

};
#endif
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"


int main() {

    List<int> ls;
    List<int>::iterator begin = ls.begin();
    List<int>::iterator end = ls.end();
    List<int>::iterator iter = begin;

    std::cout << "Attempt to retrieve data from empty list: ls.at(3)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    //std::cout << ls.at(3) << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Test: growing list does not invalidate iter" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Empty list" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "begin addr: " << &begin << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end addr: " << &end << " " << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::endl << "Add data to list: 33 " << std::endl << std::endl;
    ls.push_back(33);

    std::cout << "begin addr: " << &begin << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end addr: " << &end << " " << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Add data to list: 856 " << std::endl << std::endl;
    ls.push_back(856);

    std::cout << "begin addr: " << &begin << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end addr: " << &end << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "clear() " << std::endl << std::endl;



    ls.clear();



    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Add data to list: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++){
        ls.push_back(i);
    }


    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "data@ begin+4" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(iter + 4) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "data@ begin->end" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    iter = begin;
    while (iter++){

        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }


    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "data@ end->begin" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    iter = end;
    while (iter--){

        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }




    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "for/iter: begin->end" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    for (iter = begin; iter++;){

        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }


    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "iter arith: +4 +1 -1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------" << std::endl;
    iter = ls.begin();
    iter = iter + 4;
    std::cout << *iter << " ";
    std::cout << *(iter + 1) << " ";
    std::cout << *(iter - 1) << " ";



    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "data@: (0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++){

        std::cout << ls.at(i) << " ";

    }



    //ls.clear();


    List<std::string> ls_str;
    ls_str.push_back("Hello");
    ls_str.push_back("World");



    return 0;    // breakpoint
}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a whole bunch of code here.  Suggest you use the debugger to isolate your problem.

Comment: lol, moans if you dont post code moans if you do.
I've already used the debugger to isolate my problem to the destructor(did you read the OP)..triggered on the second line of main.

Comment: There's no evidence of a stack overflow here, just an access violation.

Comment: Your destructor does not look right.  A typical list destructor looks like:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2265981/4342498.

Comment: All your classes violate the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/241631)

Comment: It looks like `~List_iter` deletes a node that belongs to the `List`.

Comment: @ aschepler I've edited to include the evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new Element called, therefore owned by List, so only List can delete Element. List_iter doesn't require a destructor because it only contains a pointer.